# Why calendar automator event not able to launch the app?

Tags: macos, backup, calendar, automator

I would like to have regular backups of my data, so I've created a calendar event, which start start Automator application (saved locally as `Backup.app` file). But the start of app fails. The log contains the following text:

```
03.06.14 21:00:00,290 lsboxd[302]: Not allowing process 278 to launch "/Users/me/Documents/Dev/Automator/Calendar/Backup.app" because the security assessment verdict was denied.
03.06.14 21:00:00,305 lsboxd[302]: Not allowing process 278 to launch "/Users/me/Documents/Dev/Automator/Calendar/Backup.app/Contents/MacOS/Application Stub" because the security assessment verdict was denied.
03.06.14 21:00:00,305 lsboxd[302]: refusing to spawn /Users/me/Documents/Dev/Automator/Calendar/Backup.app/Contents/MacOS/Application Stub for 278 - reason -10826
```

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Try opening your Automator workflow "manually" (i.e., by opening it directly from a Finder window).  Once you've done that Calendar should be able to open it for an alert.  This seems to have worked for me.  See the section "Launching Helpers with Launch Services" near the bottom of https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html.